# Cannot get scrollbar to show

Tags: java

I have been working on this for hours now; I have read every related questions on this website, and none of the solutions work.

I have done research, I hope I will not get bashed but I do not know where to turn.

I have come up with the following code so far:

```
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(30, 35);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scroll1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 250));
        scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    contentPane.add(scroll1);
    textArea.setBounds(291, 10, 139, 250);
```

I think my problem is that I am invoking the JTextArea on a showmessagedialog, but I cannot find a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had same problem some time back.

Set the preferred size of the scroll pane rather than the text area.

Scrollbars appear when the preferred size of the component added to the scollpane is greater than the size of the scrollpane. So you have to take a look which layout manager you should use.